# Javascript post JSON data using form, but the JSON is not complete in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, base64

I have some base64 strings of png and I want to pass them to server and save the png files.

My form in javascript looks like this:

```
var $form = $("#downloadForm");
if ($form.length == 0) {
    $form = $("<form>").attr({ "target": "_blank", "id": "downloadForm",
        "method": "POST", "action": "keyword-cmp-download" }).hide();
    $("body").append($form);
}
$form.find("input").remove();
var args = {'imgs': JSON.stringify(base64_list)};
console.log(JSON.stringify(base64_list));
for (var field in args) {
    $form.append($("<input>").attr({"value":args[field], "name":field}));
}
$form.submit();
```

And in php, the code looks like this:

```
$json = Input::get('imgs'); // $json = __POST('imgs');
return $json;
```

However, the `$json` returned in PHP is not completed. It's part of `JSON.stringify(base64_list)`. And when I try to call `json_decode($json)`, `json_last_error()` returns error code 4.

I have set `post_max_size = 2048M` in `php.ini` and `LimitRequestBody 2147483647` in `httpd.conf`.

Please help me to find out the problem, thanks a lot.

Update:
`JSON.stringify(base64_list).length` returns 769283
but `strlen($json)` returns 524288

Comment: I'm not sure what is the point of the `args` object is , it will only contain a single property `imgs` which will be the json encoded string

Comment: Please elaborate on "the $json returned in PHP is not completed".

Comment: "the $json returned in PHP is not completed":  For example, result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(base64_list))` is `['abcdefghijklmn']`, but `$json` is something like `'[abcdefghijkl'`.  Since base64 string is so long, I doubt whether it is the limit of javascript post or php ?

Comment: There's really no reason to prefix all your JavaScript variables with `$`. jQuery wants to stand out by using `$` so it has earned an exception.

Comment: @tadman $ is in PHP ~

Comment: Pretty sure that's JavaScript code with `console.log` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by change `<input>` to `<textarea>`.

Since the `maxlength` of `<input>` in chrome and some other browsers is actually 524288, and set `<input maxlength = '52428800'>` do not work. The way to solve this is using `<textarea>` which seems have no limit of `maxlength`.

Thanks all

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with your data, just the output of it in HTML.